# OrmLite with BigData - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, mysql, ormlite

If I query a big table then i got a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Profiler says that com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer gets to big.

Is it possible to set a fetchsize in ormlite? I already use the Iterator, so it should consume less memory then a findall. I also tried different Types of resultset as iterator-parameter.

Setting a higher heap-size or using of limit/offset in a query should not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set a fetchsize in ormlite? I already use the Iterator, so it should consume less memory then a findall. I also tried different Types of resultset as iterator-parameter.

I don't think this is a fetchsize problem.  The default should not cause memory problems.  If you are using the iterator then you should be good.  Are you keeping all of the entities in memory or something?  Can you process them as you read them instead of keeping them all in memory?

Comment: The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError comes directly after the iterator() call of the dao. The Memory-comsumption lies outside of my code. I changed the max heapsize and it's ok. Nevertheless this should'nt be the solution.

Comment: sry, not after the iterator() -> within...callstack ends somewhere in mysql-related code.